# Python WMI _wmireg - retrieving values

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, wmi

I am trying to retrieve the values inside the Registry Object retrieved using python WMI.

```
import _winreg
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI(computer="10.31.247.8", user="devuser", password="devpass1!",namespace="root/default").StdRegProv


result, names = c.EnumKey (
hDefKey=_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
sSubKeyName="SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\MRxDAV"
)

for item in names:
    print item
```

Output:

```
EncryptedDirectories
Parameters
Security 
Enum
```

I want to retrieve the value of the string "ImagePath" present inside the directory HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\MRxDAV. The part I want to retrieve is provided in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the GetStringValue() method instead of EnumKey():

```
import _winreg
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI(computer="10.31.247.8", user="devuser", password="devpass1!",namespace="root/default").StdRegProv

result, imagePath = c.GetStringValue (
hDefKey=_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
sSubKeyName="SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\MRxDAV",
sValueName="ImagePath"
)
print imagePath
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def get_reg(self):
    # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384911(v=vs.85).aspx
    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = 2147483648
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER = 2147483649
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 2147483650
    HKEY_USERS = 2147483651
    HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG = 2147483653

    KEY_QUERY_VALUE = 1  # Required to query the values of a registry key.
    KEY_SET_VALUE = 2 # Required to create, delete, or set a registry value.
    KEY_DEFAULT_VALUE = 3  # KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_SET_VALUE Default value, allows querying, creating, deleting, or setting a registry value.
    KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY = 4 # Required to create a subkey of a registry key.
    KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS = 8 # Required to enumerate the subkeys of a registry key.
    KEY_NOTIFY = 16 # Required to request change notifications for a registry key or for subkeys of a registry key.
    KEY_CREATE = 32 # Required to create a registry key.
    DELETE = 65536 # Required to delete a registry key.
    READ_CONTROL = 131072 # Combines the STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS, and KEY_NOTIFY values.
    WRITE_DAC = 262144 # Required to modify the DACL in the object's security descriptor.
    WRITE_OWNER = 524288 # Required to change the owner in the object's security descriptor.

    #c = wmi.WMI(computer="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", user="devuser",password="devpass1!",namespace="root/default").StdRegProv
    c = wmi.WMI(find_classes=False,namespace="default",computer=self.computer).StdRegProv

    print "Methods: "
    print str(c)

    try:
        subkey = r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstations"
        name = "EnablePlainTextPassword"

        result, grants = c.CheckAccess(hDefKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sSubKeyName=subkey, uRequired=KEY_DEFAULT_VALUE);

        print "Access : " + str(grants)

        #result, value = c.GetStringValue(hDefKey=_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sSubKeyName=subkey, sValueName=name)
        #print "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE " + str(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
        #err, sids = c.EnumKey (hDefKey=2147483650, sSubKeyName=subkey)
        #for sid in sids:
        #  print sid

        # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390461(v=vs.85).aspx
        name = "OtherDomains"
        subkey = r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters"
        err, names, types = c.EnumValues (hDefKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sSubKeyName=subkey)

        for i in range(len(names)):
            if types[i] == REG_SZ:
                tipo = "Data Type: String"
                result, value = c.GetStringValue(hDefKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sSubKeyName=subkey, sValueName=names[i])
            elif types[i] == REG_EXPAND_SZ:
                tipo = "Data Type: Expanded String"
                result, value = c.GetExpandedStringValue(hDefKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sSubKeyName=subkey, sValueName=names[i])
            elif types[i] == REG_BINARY:
                tipo = "Data Type: Binary"
                result, value = c.GetBinaryValue(hDefKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sSubKeyName=subkey, sValueName=names[i])
            elif types[i] == REG_DWORD:
                tipo = "Data Type: DWORD"
                # 32 Bits
                result, value = c.GetDWORDValue(hDefKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sSubKeyName=subkey, sValueName=names[i])
                # 64 Bits
                #result, value = c.GetQWORDValue(hDefKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sSubKeyName=subkey, sValueName=names[i])
            elif types[i] == REG_MULTI_SZ:
                tipo = "Data Type: Multi String"
                result, value = c.GetMultiStringValue(hDefKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sSubKeyName=subkey, sValueName=names[i])

            print names[i] + " = " + tipo + " " + str(value)

    except Exception as e:
        print "Erro: ", str(e)
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Blocks of code without explanation are not useful